# Linq - GroupJoin

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

In Entity Framework, Given 2 System.Data.Entity.DbSets, ORDERS & USERS.

Note : There could be Orders in ORDERS table from users that are not in USERS table. In this case, CreatedUserName can be null/empty

**Relationship between Orders & Users => Many to One/None**

I want to get all records in ORDERS and matching record in USERS when available.

Below is the approach that i have tried. Just wanted to check if this can be done more efficiently

```
var OrderDetails = oContext.Orders
    .GroupJoin(
        oContext.Users,
        order => order.CreatedUserID,
        user => user.UserID,
        (order, user) => new { Order = order, User = user }
    )
    .Where(x => new List<int> { 123, 124, 125, 126 ... }.Contains(x.Order.OrderID))
    .Select(x => new OrderDetails()
    {
        OrderID = x.Order.OrderID,
        CreatedUserName = x.User.FirstOrDefault().FullName,
        .
        .
        .
    });
```

I have changed the context of the original code but the approach is same as above. Please ignore if the relationship between Orders and Users doesn't make sense.

Comment: To me, that seems to solve your purpose. But if you are looking to bring back the orders which are tied to existing users in "Users" table , then I would say, you can simply execute oContext.Users.Include(u => u.Orders).Where(...). Because, per my observations, GroupJoin performance is not optimal.

Comment: @sam Not all users are in the Users table. oContext.Users.Include() might not work in my case. Do you still think it works?

Comment: If you are after all orders (of existent as well as non-existent users), then group join is the way to go. Or you can use linq left join.

Comment: Sounds good. Thank you!